# How to prove the polar decomposition of unbounded operators?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators

> Let $ T $ be a closed, densely defined operator on a Hilbert space $ H $. Then there exists a positive self-adjoint operator $ A $, $ D(A)=D(T) $ and a isometric operator $ V:R(A)\to \overline{R(T)} $ where $ R(T)=T(H) $ such that $ T=VA $. Moreover, if $ \ker A=\ker T $, such decomposition is unique.

I know that in the polar decomposition of bounded operators or matrices, one need to consider the operator $ (T^*T)^{1/2} $. However, here I can not do the same procidure by imitating the methods for bounded operators. Can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: This is proved in Weidmann's book *Linear operators in Hilbert spaces*. The proof should be essentially the same as in the bounded case, though: Define again $A=(T^*T)^{1/2}$ and take it from there.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I find that in Weidmann's book, it is an exercise. Can you say more explicitly?

Comment: In my (German) edition, this is Theorem 7.20(b), which is proved in the book. (You seem to have slightly mixed up the statement: $V$ maps $V:\overline{R(A)}\to\overline{R(T)}$.)

Comment: You do need von Neumann's theorem saying that $T^*T$ is self-adjoint for any closed densely defined $T$. The rest should be quite routine.